# Fill matrixes that end in different number in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I would like to fill several matrices in a for loop.

My for loop looks like this:

```
for(i in 1:19){

assign(paste("accurancy_train", i, sep="_"), matrix(nrow=5, ncol=10))
assign(paste("accurancy_test", i, sep="_"), matrix(nrow=5, ncol=10))

for(r in 1:10) {

 #something

 for(t in 1:5) {
  a <- 1

 accurancy_train_"i"[t,r] <- a #this is the problematic part
 accurancy_test_"i"[t,r] <- a  #this is the problematic part
}
}
}
```

My expected output in this toy example should be

```
>accurancy_train_1

    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   1   1     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]   1   1     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[3,]   1   1     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[4,]   1   1     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[5,]   1   1     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1

>accurancy_train_2

    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   1   1     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]   1   1     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[3,]   1   1     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[4,]   1   1     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[5,]   1   1     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

.
.
.

```
>accurancy_train_19

    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   1   1     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]   1   1     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[3,]   1   1     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[4,]   1   1     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[5,]   1   1     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

I don't want to create a list, in the end, I will vectorize each table and then I want to make a cbind to have a single table. But I am not sure how to fill the tables from 1 to 19. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean to do, but maybe this?... `replicate(19, (matrix(1, nrow = 5, ncol = 10)))`?

Comment: why not a list ? you can merge everything afterwards anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get`, `assign` and `[<-` instead of `accurancy_train_"i"[t,r] <- a`

```
for(i in 1:19){
  assign(paste("accurancy_train", i, sep="_"), matrix(nrow=5, ncol=10))
  assign(paste("accurancy_test", i, sep="_"), matrix(nrow=5, ncol=10))
  for(r in 1:10) {
    for(t in 1:5) {
      a <- 1
      tt  <- paste0("accurancy_train_",i)
      assign(tt, "[<-"(get(tt),t,r, a)) #accurancy_train_"i"[t,r] <- a
      tt  <- paste0("accurancy_test_",i)
      assign(tt, "[<-"(get(tt),t,r, a)) #accurancy_test_"i"[t,r] <- a
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using lists (avoid: *assign*, *eval*, *parse*) see this example:

```
# make list of matrices (as example only 3 matrices)
myTrain <- lapply(1:3, function(i) matrix(nrow = 2, ncol = 3))
myTest <- lapply(1:3, function(i) matrix(nrow = 2, ncol = 3))
# give them names
names(myTrain) <- paste0("accurancy_train_", 1:3)
names(myTest) <- paste0("accurancy_test_", 1:3)

# loop as usual here we have 3 matrices
for(i in 1:3){
  for(r in 1:3) {

    #something

    for(t in 1:2) {
      a <- 1
      # access the relevant matrix by index (i) and assign new values
      myTrain[[ i ]][ t, r ] <- a
      myTest[[ i ]][ t, r ] <- a
    }
  }
}

# then clutter your environment if required
list2env(myTrain, globalenv())
list2env(myTest, globalenv())

# test
ls(pattern = "acc*")
# [1] "accurancy_test_1"  "accurancy_test_2"  "accurancy_test_3"
# [4] "accurancy_train_1" "accurancy_train_2" "accurancy_train_3"
```

Comment: good point @zx8754, to put the variables back into the environment using list2env. I did not know of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work, but is it really good to have 10 variables floating around? You can always keep all your matrics in a list. You vectorize them and cbind using do.call or reduce. Below is a solution for your example:

```
for(i in 1:2){
assign(paste("accurancy_train", i, sep="_"), matrix(nrow=5, ncol=10))
}

for(i in 1:2){
    for(r in 1:10){
        for(t in 1:5){
          eval(parse(text=paste0("accurancy_train_",i,"[t,r]","<- i*r*t")))
          }
      }
   }

And you can check the result

     accurancy_train_1
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
    [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
    [2,]    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18    20
    [3,]    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27    30
    [4,]    4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36    40
    [5,]    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45    50
```

But I would really suggest keeping them in a list:

```
accuracy_list = lapply(1:2,function(i)matrix(nrow=5, ncol=10))
names(accuracy_list) = paste("accurancy_train", 1:2, sep="_")

for(i in names(accuracy_list)){
#basically replace all values at one shot
accuracy_list[[i]][1:5,1:10] = runif(50)
}
```